# I am a new user of linux and was told it was the easyest to install and use but

Tags: vlc

My main problem is that the latest version no longer supports vlc player , vlc player is the only app that does what it says play all formats.
This should be an urgent fix.

John

johnfc1@optusnet.com.au

Comment: What's the OS??

Comment: We would like to help, but you need to provide enough details in order for anyone to understand your situation and make an attempt to answer.  Please review "[How to Ask](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)" for tips on how to improve your chances of getting an answer.  Then come back and [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1278523/edit) your question.  Please be as specific as possible.  Tell us exactly what you're doing and exactly how your device responds. Provide full unredacted errors w/ line breaks. FYI: VLC is supported on every version and flavor of Ubuntu that has a desktop.

Comment: I've had no issues with `vlc` in any release or *flavor* of Ubuntu, but you've provided no details. I tend to use *flavors* which provide more codecs than Ubuntu itself can provide (due to *free* software choices) and `vlc` is easily added anyway.

Comment: I have install VLC about a dozen times in the last two days as part of another project. `sudo apt install vlc` should install it. You will likely need to okay the install of some codecs depending on what you are using it for.

Answer (score 3):

1. hi there, the command `sudo snap install vlc` should install the vlc player on your ubuntu.
2. if it is not supported you can download it manually from https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html just choose the version you need.
3. please comment if that works out, if not, please comment the output for we can solve the issue togther.

Comment: You don't even need to use snap.  The package is available in `universe`.  `sudo apt update` + `sudo apt install vlc` will do the job in case the author of the question doesn't want to use a snap.

Comment: John Cousens - if the answer was helpful please accept the answer, if not, please update the status for we can keep trying to solve the problem.